# Documents with new field added before mapping update not queryable via new field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index that for one reason or another we've added fields to that don't exist in our mapping. For example:

```
{
  "name": "Bob" // Exists in mapping
  "age": 12     // doesn't existing in mapping
}
```

After updating the mapping to add the `age` field, any document we add the `age` field to is queryable, but none of the documents that had `age` added before we updated the mapping are queryable.

Is there a way to tell Elastic to make those older documents queryable, not just any net-new/updated after the mapping update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This implies that you must have `dynamic: false` in your mapping, i.e. whenever you send a new field, you prevent ES from creating it automatically.

Once you have updated your mapping, you can then simply call [`_update_by_query`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html) on your index in order to update it and have it reindex the data it contains with the new mappings.

Your queries will then work also on the "older" data.